# CSS adding elements inside elements?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 elements "Block" "button1" "button2" and "label".

I want the block to have the buttons inside it by CSS. this can be done by HTML like this :

```
<b class = "block">
   <g class="Label"> </g>
   <a class="button1"> </a>
   <a class="button2"> </a>
</b>
```

but it'll take so much space if done 50 times in one page.

and I want a way to change button1,2 'href' with as less a possible lines of code.

Comment: Could you clarify what the end-result should be, I don't think I understand what you're asking for. Though I think you'll probably need to use JavaScript, not CSS.

Comment: You cannot do this using CSS alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is meant to modify the appearance of a page, and not to be used for adding content - although pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after` are commonly used for decorative purposes (e.g. adding arrows, or for layout hacks)

Have you considered using a JS-based method? You can loop through all the `.block` elements and then insert the label and buttons in each of them.

An example of a JS-based method would be: (assuming that you're using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".block").each(function() {
        // Create elements to append
        var apnd = '<element></element>';

        // Append the created elements
        $(apnd).appendTo($(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to achieve this would be use a parameterised jQuery function that adds or modifies the "href" value of each button of a given CSS class (with minor variations of the assigned href based on a given parameter - if that suits).

Sorry, to directly address the question, I agree with the other posters in that this can't be achieved using CSS alone.

Comment: thanks for the answer ,I asked the question after searching the web so much and didn't find it. so I think you are right